# How to insert custom emoji (small pictures) into Textinput of React Native?

Tags: react-native, emoji, textinput

I'm building a BBS APP, and an user could insert custom emoji (with custom keyboard I created) into Textinput when they are publishing or replying a article.

For example, I have a smiley picture, and it will map to a code like [:custom_smile_code:]. When a user type text in Textinput, if he/she taps the picture, I hope it will insert the picture into Textinput, but how can I implement it? if it's just a View, I can use Image component, but this is Textinput. The only thing I can do it insert [:custom_smile_code:] instead of picture.

Is there any way I can insert small picture (something like custom emoji) into Textinput? (Also, I need to remove it with delete button and move the cursor around it)

Comment: Try it might help you .  https://github.com/goshakkk/react-native-simple-emoji-picker

Comment: @SyedZainAli - Thanks, but the library is for standard emoji, right?

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17468 in RN repo.