# Insert custom emoji image in TextInput in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I want to use custom emoji in my application, so that emojis are consistent over different platforms. So I have to add some small images in TextInput component to achieve this. However it is not possible in React Native yet.

I mean something like this:

```js
<TextInput>
  <Text>Some Text Here...</Text>
  <Image
    source={require('./src/assets/1f602.png')}
    style={styles.image}
  />
</TextInput>
```

This doesn't show image on IOS, and has some problems Android too. I know this is possible in both Android and IOS but React Native implementation doesn't allow us to do so.

I have read these posts and issues:

- [How to insert custom emoji (small pictures) into Textinput of React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48033885/how-to-insert-custom-emoji-small-pictures-into-textinput-of-react-native)
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17468

Can you help me achieve what I want? How to use custom emoji in TextInput?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use images inside textInput. Maybe it can be added in the future versions of react native.

But for now, we can use some RTE(Rich Text Editor) like [this one](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor). This way we can add images into text editor and work with it with  ease.